# How to switch through scenes in JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

Hey guys so i was wondering. How can I for example make my main window and when the user types something or clicks something the scene changes and by that i mean everything chances new images new stuff but without changing window or at least not having to pop up a new one and have to close the other. And then for example if he clicks something on the new window he will go back to the main one. I'm new at JFrame. Thanks for your time.
Edit: Here is my code (Testing JFrame code)

```
public class ActionListenerTest extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public ActionListenerTest(){
    super("Yeah");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setSize(800,800);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);


    ImageIcon image=new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("FileName2.png"));
    JPanel p =new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JPanel p2 =new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JLabel lbl= new JLabel(image);
    JButton b=new JButton("Button Test");
    JButton b2=new JButton("Button Test 2");
    lbl.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Men... you weak..","WOOOOO",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            JDialog d=new JDialog();
            d.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            d.setSize(300,300);
            d.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            d.setTitle("Dialog TEST");
            d.setVisible(true);
            JButton test=new JButton("TESTING");
            JPanel testP= new JPanel();
            testP.add(test);
            d.add(testP, BorderLayout.WEST);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        }
    });
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hey wanna hang out sometime?","WOOOOO",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    });


    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets=new Insets(150,20,30,20);
    gbc.gridx=3;
    gbc.gridy=2;
    p.add(b, gbc);
    gbc.gridx=3;
    gbc.gridy=3;
    p.add(b2, gbc);
    gbc.gridx=15;
    gbc.gridy=15;
    p2.add(lbl, gbc);
    add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    ActionListenerTest a = new ActionListenerTest();
       a.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Please show what all you have done to achieve this problem them someone can help you http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [SWING - CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), [Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_cardlayout.htm). Your welcome!

**OR**

If you have to change your panel frequently or want to do it your own. I suggest you to create an array of panels set `BorderLayout` on your `JFrame` (which is by default) and just swap your panels accordingly in buttons listener. For smooth look all panels bounds should be same.

Answer (score 0):

Use JPanels in an array and set their visibility accordingly.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Please post what you have already tried (for learning you must try to put everything in code) and someone here will help you with the modifications.